# flutter / dart reflectable package : Not reflecting base/super class members

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, reflection, reflector

```
import 'package:reflection_test2/common/reflect/Reflector.dart';

@reflector
class Base
{
  String s1;
}

@reflector
class Sub extends Base
{
  String s2;
}

ClassMirror classMirror = reflector.reflectType(Sub);
```

=> Here classMirror reflects only s2, not reflecting base/super class member s1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you need to do with `s1` field, but one way to access it is listed below.
I hope it helps.

```
class Reflector extends Reflectable {
  // config reflect capabilities
  const Reflector() : super(invokingCapability, declarationsCapability, typeRelationsCapability);
}
```

```
ClassMirror classMirror = reflector.reflectType(Sub);
// print all instance members of the superclass (e.g. toString, s1, etc.)
classMirror.superclass.instanceMembers.forEach((key, value) => print(value.simpleName));
```

Comment: thanks Zoran, your 'classMirror.superclass...' did the trick. In Java there is no need to specify superclass, reflection there brings both base & subclasses members combined so i was expecting that.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped @Arif. Hint: Access to all "combined" members declarations should be possible like this: `classMirror.instanceMembers.forEach((key, value) => print(value.simpleName));`. Note that this requires `declarationsCapability`.